# Getting error when have same framework used with another framework and main application

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

My application consist of the main app, 2 custom frameworks and 1 framework filled with objects. I want to use the object framework in the main app and both of the children frameworks but I am getting 
Class is implemented in both One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined. error

One of my extra frameworks is in swift and the other is in objective c but that shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

It's the common problem, when including frameworks, that contains the same submodule. Duplicate error happens because you have the same symbols inside your binary, so, when you include both, linker fails.

The are several ways to solve this.

1. Rename classes inside "parent" framework, which you include, with another domain prefix (the common way to do so, if you have access to source code)
2. Also, if you can build all this frameworks separately, maybe [this link](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-using-sub-projects-git-submodules-to-create-a-framework-in-ios/) could help (it's git submodule feature, which also helpful when you have to deal with Pods, i think it could give an idea, how to solve your issue)

Hope this helps.